# Image overlap on top of container with content

Tags: html, css, layout

What is the best way to have an image on top of a card with content underneath it?

I have tried negative margins but I have had no luck on with this approach.

I attached an image of what the look and feel I am going for: 
[image]

Here is my attempt on code

```css
.card {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.card__section {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.card__inner {
  background: black;
  padding: calc(35px + 30%) 35px 35px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.card__image {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto -30%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="card">
        <section class="card__section">
          <img
            class="card__image"
            src="http://via.placeholder.com/340x220"
            alt=""
          />
          <div class="card__inner">
            <h1>
              This is a static template, there is no bundler or bundling
              involved!
            </h1>
          </div>
        </section>
      </a>
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Comment: @Rob - I added code to this ticket.

Comment: Voting to reopen since the OP's code has been added to the question, and is half-working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add below css

```
.card__section {
  overflow: visible;
}
.card__image {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
section.card__section {
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

and put your image in `card__inner` div

see https://codesandbox.io/s/card-hover-5n0yf?file=/index.html:450-461

[image]

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there! There are two things that need to be updated:

**1. Remove extra `%` in `.card__image`**

```
.card__image {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto -30%%;  // <-- Remove extra % at the end.
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

**2. Adjust `padding` in `.card__inner` due to negative margin on previous element.**

```
.card__inner {
  background: black;
  // Update padding to below. Negative margin on previous element needs to be added to the top padding.
  padding: calc(35px + 30%) 35px 35px;  
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/card-hover-wiilf